# Is there a 35th edition of "On Writing Well"?

Tags: writing, writing-style, books, style-manuals, writing-advice

My English teacher recommended Zinsser's "On Writing Well" as a supplement to my reading of E.B. White's "The Elements of Style". While I know that Zinsser's 30th edition exists, I have come across an online apparition of the 35th edition: http://books.google.com/books/about/On_Writing_Well_35th_Anniversary_Edition.html?id=rIG5SgAACAAJ. Does a 35th edition of the book actually exist, or have I met a myth since I cannot find it?

Comment: There's probably a difference between a special edition celebrating the 35th anniversary of its release and a 35th edition.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes a 35th edition of the book actually does exist](http://www.betterworldbooks.com/on-writing-well-35th-anniversary-edition-id-0061999903.aspx)

Comment: But I cannot purchase the book; it seems to be out of stock everywhere.

Comment: http://www.booksamillion.com/p/Writing-Well-Anniversary/William-Knowlton-Zinsser/9780061999901